I am getting error that dbus package is not installed in virtual env
I am using virtual env to run my program, but it show this error every time I run my code:
 UserWarning: The Python dbus package is not installed.
Try installing it with your distribution's package manager, it is usually called python-dbus or python3-dbus, but you might have to try dbus-python instead, e.g. when using pip.
  warnings.warn(msg)

I tried to install dbus package but it shows that its already installed on my system, so I tried running the code again, but, no luck - it shows the same error, that dbus isn't installed!

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take the time to explain clearly how you're getting this error and with what code.  If you're using a virtual env, how are you running this?  How was the dbus package installed?  Which dbus package did you install?  What python version are you using?

The error tell you, in your current env this package isn’t installed.

Using apt will install into dist-packages while using pip with a venv will install in to site-packages.
If you create your venv with the --system-site-packages then that will pick up the apt package from dist-packages.
If you do pip install dbus-python when a "normal" venv is active that should work also.
